# org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException:

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm using the following jar files:

```
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
poi-3.9-20121203.jar
poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
```

Code:

```
package ExcelTest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("G:\\Selenium Jar Files\\TestData\\Data.xls"));

            //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            //Iterate through each rows one by one
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                //For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    //Check the cell type and format accordingly
                    switch (cell.getCellType())
                    {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "t");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "t");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            file.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:41)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:218)
    at ExcelTest.Test.main(Test.java:21)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:199)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:665)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:274)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
    ... 2 more
```

I have gone through the link but was unable to solve the issue.
[Getting Exception(org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exception - no content type [M1.13]) when reading xlsx file using Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758364/getting-exceptionorg-apache-poi-openxml4j-exceptions-when-reading-xlsx-file-us)

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Are you sure it's really a .xlsx file? You often get that exception if you try to open something like a zip file

Comment: it is an .xls file, i have manually opened and checked it

Comment: For anyone new coming across this, try upgrading your version of Apache POI first. POI 3.15 has more descriptive exceptions in this case, eg [ODFNotOfficeXmlFileException](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/exceptions/ODFNotOfficeXmlFileException.html) and [OLE2NotOfficeXmlFileException](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/exceptions/OLE2NotOfficeXmlFileException.html)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You are trying to read `xls` with explicit implementation poi classes for `xlsx`.

G:\Selenium Jar Files\TestData\Data.**xls**

Either use [`HSSFWorkbook`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html) and [`HSSFSheet`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html) classes or make your implementation more generic by using shared interfaces, like;

Change:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
```

To:

```
 org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
```

And Change:

```
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

To:

```
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

Comment: @PopoFibo can you solve the same problem for XWPFDocument?? please

Comment: It helped me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You are trying to access an XLS file. However, you are using XSSFWorkbook and XSSFSheet class objects. These classes are mainly used for XLSX files.

For XLS file: `HSSFWorkbook` & `HSSFSheet`
For XLSX file: `XSSFSheet` & `XSSFSheet`

So in place of `XSSFWorkbook` use `HSSFWorkbook` and in place of `XSSFSheet` use `HSSFSheet`.

So your code should look like this after the changes are made:

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
package my_default;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

        // Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = createSheet(workbook, "Sheet 1", false);

        // XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);//Don't use this line
        // because you get Sheet index (1) is out of range (no sheets)

        //Write some information in the cells or do what you want
        XSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow(0);
        XSSFCell r1c2 = row1.createCell(0);
        r1c2.setCellValue("NAME");
        XSSFCell r1c3 = row1.createCell(1);
        r1c3.setCellValue("AGE");


        //Save excel to HDD Drive
        File pathToFile = new File("D:\\test.xlsx");
        if (!pathToFile.exists()) {
            pathToFile.createNewFile();
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pathToFile);
        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static XSSFSheet createSheet(XSSFWorkbook wb, String prefix, boolean isHidden) {
    XSSFSheet sheet = null;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
        String sName = wb.getSheetName(i);
        if (sName.startsWith(prefix))
            count++;
    }

    if (count > 0) {
        sheet = wb.createSheet(prefix + count);
    } else
        sheet = wb.createSheet(prefix);

    if (isHidden)
        wb.setSheetHidden(wb.getNumberOfSheets() - 1, XSSFWorkbook.SHEET_STATE_VERY_HIDDEN);

        return sheet;
    }

}
```