# Reading contents from .xls or .xlsx file using Java and Apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am running below my code in STS with java 1.7 version on ubuntu 14 version and I am unable solve the issue even though I have tested below 2 programs by adding all the jars of Apache poi 3.9 version once and with version 3.2 for second time. but every time it is giving almost same error
Kindly suggest me some thing
Thanks in advance.

Following is my code to read data from `.xlsx` file

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
public class ReadData {

    public static void main(String a[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

        try {
            File file = new File("Test.xlsx");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            XSSFWorkbook hwb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

and error I am getting is

`Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:273)
    at com.axxera.selenium.ReadData.main(ReadData.java:18)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:201)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:684)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:275)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)`

And below code for reading data from `.xls` file

```
public class ReadData {

    public static void main(String a[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

        try {
            File file = new File("Test.xls");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

and above code is generating this error

`Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:128)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:112)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:300)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:400)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:381)
    at com.axxera.selenium.ReadData.main(ReadData.java:17)`

Comment: Did you import all necessary JARs of POI?

Comment: Can you list out which JARs you have imported?

Comment: take a look at this question.. may be this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992071/org-apache-poi-poixmlexception-org-apache-poi-openxml4j-exceptions-invalidforma

Comment: /home/axxera/Jars/ApachePoi/poi-3.13/poi-scratchpad-3.13-20150929.jar
/home/axxera/Jars/ApachePoi/poi-3.13/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13-20150929.jar
/home/axxera/Jars/ApachePoi/poi-3.13/poi-ooxml-3.13-20150929.jar
/home/axxera/Jars/ApachePoi/poi-3.13/poi-excelant-3.13-20150929.jar
/home/axxera/Jars/ApachePoi/poi-3.13/poi-examples-3.13-20150929.jar
/home/axxera/Jars/ApachePoi/poi-3.13/poi-3.13-20150929.jar
/home/axxera/Jars/ApachePoi/poi-3.13/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar

Comment: /home/axxera/Jars/ApachePoi/poi-3.13/lib/junit-4.12.jar
/home/axxera/Jars/ApachePoi/poi-3.13/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
/home/axxera/Jars/ApachePoi/poi-3.13/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar
/home/axxera/Jars/ApachePoi/poi-3.13/ooxml-lib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar

Comment: above are 3.13 jars and also i have tested with 3.9 FINAL jar

Comment: HI @awsome it is giving following error

org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:201)
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:684)
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:275)
 at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:209)
 at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:168)
 at com.axxera.selenium.ReadData.main(ReadData.java:21)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you saved `xls` under `xlsx` and visa versa.

Try `Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file | inputStream)`. It opens file independent of the file extension.

Comment: Thanks a lot 
I renamed .xls file to .xlsx and copied to other location

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine with poi-3.5-FINAL.jar and with .xls file

Answer (score 0):

you'r code in OK for .xls . 
but you should handle the another file extension (`.xlsx`)