# TestNG XML file failed to invoke/create the XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, xml, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, testng

I have a hybrid framework which takes the input and output operations in the Excel file. For the operations I have used the Apache POI 3.9.

When I run the testng.xml, the file exactly stops at the creation of XSSFWorkbook object.

When I debug the testng.xml it executes well.

Somewhere I missed a logic, kindly guide me to reach out.

**Test Engine**

```
package runner;
public class TestEngine {


protected static ExtentReports report;
public static ActionKeywords actionKeywords;
private static WebDriver screenDriver;

@BeforeTest

public void browserStartUp(){
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",Constant.chromeDriver);
report = new ExtentReports(Constant.reportLocation,true);
}



@Parameters({ "browser" })
@Test
public void runner(String browser) throws Exception,CustomException {

 Path metapath = Paths.get(Constant.filePath+Constant.metaDataFileName);
 Path testpath = Paths.get(Constant.filePath+Constant.testDataFileName);

 //Check the meta data and test data file is exists.
 if(Files.exists(metapath) && Files.exists(testpath)){  

 String executionIndicator=null,testCaseSheet_testCaseID=null,
 testCaseFlow=null,screen_testCaseID=null,
 screenName=null,allScreens[]=null;

 int noOfTestCase,testData_Rows,metaData_Rows,testData_Columns;
 ExcelUtility eUtility = new ExcelUtility();
 noOfTestCase = eUtility.getNumberOfRows(Constant.filePath,    Constant.testDataFileName, Constant.flowSheetName);
 System.out.println("Number of test case"+noOfTestCase);                
}
```

**Excel Utility**

```
public class ExcelUtility {

private File file = null;
private FileInputStream inputStream = null;
private FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
public Workbook workbook =null;

private Sheet sheet = null;
private Row row = null;
private static Cell cell =null;

private int totalRows=0;
private int totalCols=0;

//To get the sheet name from workbook
public Sheet getSheet(String filePath,String fileName,String sheetName) throws Exception{
    try {

         workbook = readWorkbook(filePath, fileName, sheetName); 

         sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);

    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.getStackTrace();
        throw ex;
    }
    return sheet;
}
public void display(){
    System.out.println("Test");
}

public Workbook readWorkbook(String filePath,String fileName,String sheetName) throws Exception{
    try {
        file =    new File(filePath+fileName);
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);     
        String fileExtensionName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));
          if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xlsx")){
             System.out.println("test");
             workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
             System.out.println("testOne");

        }
         else if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xls")){
             workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        }     
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        throw ex;
    }
    return workbook;
}

//To get the total number of row in the excel sheet
public int getNumberOfRows(String filePath,String fileName,String sheetName) throws Exception{
try {

     sheet=getSheet(filePath, fileName, sheetName);

     totalRows = sheet.getLastRowNum(); 

    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        throw ex;
    }
 return totalRows;
}
```

**TestNG.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Firefox Test">
   <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="runner.TestEngine"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test --> 
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

On Run, in the read workbook method the value **testone** is not displayed in the console log.

But when I remove the **parallel = tests** from the suite tag, It works well in one by one order. It fails to work in parallel.

**Exception**

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:403)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:155)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:207)
    at utility.ExcelUtility.readWorkbook(ExcelUtility.java:57)
    at utility.ExcelUtility.getSheet(ExcelUtility.java:40)
    at utility.ExcelUtility.getNumberOfRows(ExcelUtility.java:73)
    at testEngine.TestEngine.main(TestEngine.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:60)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error: Unexpected end of file after null
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.readFrom(StylesTable.java:167)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.<init>(StylesTable.java:92)
    ... 36 more
```

**Exception [After removing the Static in Excel Utility class]**

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:41)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:204)
    at utility.ExcelUtility.readWorkbook(ExcelUtility.java:65)
    at utility.ExcelUtility.getSheet(ExcelUtility.java:48)
    at utility.ExcelUtility.existingWriteExcel(ExcelUtility.java:182)
    at testEngine.TestEngine.main(TestEngine.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:39)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:393)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:178)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:662)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:269)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: What do you mean stop? Does test throw exception? Could you create example project on github?

Comment: I get an exception like **org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ExcelUtility class is static, so in parallel execution you are getting concurrent modification because same instance is shared between all threads. And that is why it works fine without it. So solution is to make your ExcelUtility class stateless or create new instance for each thread (e.g. remove static, or make it ThreadLocal).

Comment: I removed the static keyword and it started to work well. Great!

Comment: I have got an another exception called **org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]**

Comment: I have added the exception in the question.

Comment: could you add updated full version of  ExcelUtility?

Comment: Can we speak through chat. I have added the updated TestEngine and Excel Utility class.

Comment: You can contact me via github. Any way it seems your are trying to read `xls` using `XSSFWorkbook` which is used for `xlsx`. See related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992071/org-apache-poi-poixmlexception-org-apache-poi-openxml4j-exceptions-invalidforma)

Comment: I have .xlsx file only and I try to read the XSSFWorkbook only. What is your github name?

Comment: I have sent you inventation in gitter