# FileOutputStream webdata=new FileOutputStream();

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

As soon as fileoutstream is executed it is changing the file format.
Below is my code:

```
FileInputStream input=new FileInputStream(path);
System.out.println("input"); 
XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(input);
System.out.println("wb");
XSSFSheet sh=wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
System.out.println("sh");
XSSFRow row=sh.getRow(2);
System.out.println("row");
FileOutputStream webdata=new FileOutputStream(path);
System.out.println("wedata");
row.createCell(2).setCellValue("hi");
System.out.println("print");
wb.write(webdata);
System.out.println("end");
```

> org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.NotOfficeXmlFileException

Comment: Where is the exception thrown from?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this Question and answer may halp you.

[Getting Exception(org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exception - no content type [M1.13]) when reading xlsx file using Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758364/getting-exceptionorg-apache-poi-openxml4j-exception-no-content-type-m1-13)

> Can Excel really load this file? I'd expect it wouldn't be able to, as
>   the exception is most commonly triggered by giving POI a regular .zip
>   file! I suspect your file isn't valid, hence the exception

I hope it helps.

Juan